# UIButton appears different on runtime

Tags: ios

I just added a button to the storyboard, but when I run the simulator it appears like in the following picture:

[image]

Can someone explain me why this is happening ? For the record I am using Google+ Platform for IOS sdk.

Comment: Do you use Autolayout? If so you can [easily add the missing constraints to you button.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html)

Comment: Yeah, I was using Autolayout, but now I have disable it, and the text appears next to the blue box, why does the blue box appears ? That is what I don't understand

Comment: Do you change the button's background anywhere? (either in IB oder in code (maybe globally using UIButton's appearance proxy))?

Comment: No, I just added from the Object Library and changed the text colour. Thats it.

Answer (score 2):

Is kinda weird. Did you set it up programmatically on your view controller class? if not, try adding it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you include GooglePlus.bundle in your project, the button will appear like that. It includes the GPPSignIn button.